# Json Web Signature according to RFC 7515 with NewtonSoft Json.NET

Tags: json, asp.net-core, json.net, .net-core, digital-signature

I'm searching for a library to generate and verify Json Web Signatures according to RFC 7515, with .NET Core.

We're currently using Json.NET as serializer, so solutions compatible to it are preferred.

Thanks!

(We don't want to roll our own implementation, as crypto is hard, and getting it right is even harder, so we prefer a proven implementation if one exists...)

Comment: This was asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372229/does-asp-net-core-support-json-web-signatures-for-restful-web-apis) but without an answer.  You could take a look at [Jwt.Net](https://github.com/jwt-dotnet/jwt).

Comment: Jwt.Net seems more like a JWT implementation coming with just the subset of JWS needed for JWT, than a complete and self-standing JWS implementation.

Comment: Jwt.Net also doesn't support a strictly dotnet core (2) implementation.